# Error(13,34): PLS-00201: identifier 'D.BNDNG_TYP' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I wrote a procedure where i am trying to insert value from source to destination table, i used bulk collect in order to execute the data for large amount of data.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST2 (
    p_array_size IN NUMBER
) IS

CURSOR cur1 IS SELECT DISTINCT
        *
                        FROM
        test;
                        
        
        CURSOR cur3 IS SELECT * FROM test;
        
        CURSOR cur2( BND_TYPE d.bndng_typ%TYPE, BND_VAL d.bndng_val%TYPE, FINANCIAL_INST_ID d.financial_institution_id%TYPE, PRDCT_ID d.prdct_id%TYPE, 
            PRDCT_SUB_ID d.prdct_sub_id%TYPE, INSTRUMENT_ID d.instrmnt_id%TYPE) IS SELECT
                                d.*
                                FROM
                                test1 d,
                                (
                                    SELECT
                                    b.prdct_id,
                                    
                                    FROM
                                        test2 a,
                                        test1 b
                                    WHERE
                                        a.ir_id = b.ir_id
                                        AND   a.price_component_id = b.price_component_id
                                        AND   a.financial_institution_id = b.financial_institution_id
                                    GROUP BY
                                        b.prdct_id,
                                        
                                ) e
                                WHERE
                                d.prdct_id = e.prdct_id
                                AND   d.bndng_typ = BND_TYPE
                                AND   d.bndng_val = BND_VAL
                                AND   d.financial_institution_id = FINANCIAL_INST_ID
                                AND   d.prdct_id = PRDCT_ID
                                AND   d.prdct_sub_id = PRDCT_SUB_ID
                                AND   d.instrmnt_id = INSTRUMENT_ID  ;
                                
                                
        
        TYPE loan_data_tbl IS TABLE OF cur1%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
        loan_data loan_data_tbl;
        
        TYPE loanrate_tbl IS TABLE OF cur2%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
        loan_rate loanrate_tbl;
        
        BEGIN 
        
            DECLARE
                v_noofDays NUMBER:=0;
                currentDt DATE;
            BEGIN 
                    SELECT * INTO  currentDt FROM dt;
                    
                    BEGIN
                    
                        IF cur1%Isopen Then
                            Close cur1;
                        End IF;
                        
                        IF cur2%Isopen Then
                            Close cur2;
                        End IF;
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        OPEN cur1;
                        LOOP
                                FETCH cur1 BULK COLLECT INTO loan_data LIMIT p_array_size;
                                EXIT WHEN loan_data.COUNT = 0;
                                
                                FOR i IN 1..loan_data.COUNT         
                                LOOP
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                             OPEN cur3;
                                        
                                    OPEN cur2(loan_data(i).bndng_typ, loan_data(i).bndng_val,loan_data(i).financial_institution_id,
                                    loan_data(i).prdct_id, loan_data(i).prdct_sub_id, loan_data(i).instrmnt_id);
                                             loop
                                        
                                    FETCH cur2 BULK COLLECT INTO loan_rate LIMIT p_array_size;
                                    EXIT WHEN loan_rate.COUNT = 0;
                                    
                                    FOR j IN 1..loan_rate.COUNT
                                    LOOP 
                                    
                                        IF(cur3.POS_NUM = loan_data(i).POS_NUM AND cur3.POS_TYPE = loan_data(i).POS_TYPE    
                                            AND cur3.PRICE_COMPONENT_ID = loan_rate(j).PRICE_COMPONENT_ID
                                            AND cur3.RPRTD_TILL_DT = loan_data(i).RPRTD_TILL_DT) THEN 
                                        
                                            update test SET SEQ_NUM=1,
                                                WHERE SEQ_NUM=2;
                                                
                                        ELSE 
                                        
                                            INSERT INTO test VALUES (
                                            ....
                                            ....
                                            
                                        );
                                                  
                                             END IF;
                                        COMMIT;                     
                                    END LOOP;
                                END LOOP;
                                
                            CLOSE cur2;
                        CLOSE cur1;
                        
                    END LOOP;
                         END LOOP;
            
            CLOSE cur1;
        END;
    END;    
End ;
/
```

In above procedure, i removed some column names for security purpose.

I am getting two errors one is

**PLS-00201: identifier 'D.BNDNG_TYP' must be declared** and
**PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'cur3' reference is out of scope**

if any one can help to solve this.

Comment: if I see it correctly, there's a ';' missing at the end of cursor cur1 declaration

Comment: Also same comments as for your other post about this procedure - formatting, parameter naming etc: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62600904/230471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cursor, You cannot provide the type referring to alias from cursor query. You need to just provide the table name `test1` instead of alias `d`.

```
CURSOR cur2( BND_TYPE test1.bndng_typ%TYPE, 
             BND_VAL test1.bndng_val%TYPE, 
             FINANCIAL_INST_ID test1.financial_institution_id%TYPE, 
             PRDCT_ID test1.prdct_id%TYPE, 
             PRDCT_SUB_ID test1.prdct_sub_id%TYPE, 
             INSTRUMENT_ID test1.instrmnt_id%TYPE)
IS SELECT
.....
```

Comment: Then how can it know the datatype of the parameter we are passing in, i tried removing it but it dint work

Comment: Thanks, its working now..do u have any idea of how cursor cur3  can we rewritten, because i am getting the error metioned above "subprogram or cursor 'cur3' reference is out of scope"

Answer (score 0):

This is untested as I don't have your tables and data, but as a first refactoring I would start with this type of structure:

```
create or replace procedure test2
as
    cursor loan_data_cur
        ( bnd_type cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.bndng_typ%type
        , bnd_val cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.bndng_val%type
        , financial_inst_id cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.financial_institution_id%type
        , prdct_id cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.prdct_id%type
        , prdct_sub_id cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.prdct_sub_id%type
        , instrument_id cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.instrmnt_id%type )
    is
        select d.*
        from   test1 d
               join ( select b.prdct_id
                      from   test2 a
                             join test1 b
                                  on  b.ir_id = a.ir_id
                                  and b.price_component_id = a.price_component_id
                                  and b.financial_institution_id = a.financial_institution_id
                      group by b.prdct_id ) e
               on  d.prdct_id = e.prdct_id
        where  d.bndng_typ = loan_data_cur.bnd_type
        and    d.bndng_val = loan_data_cur.bnd_val
        and    d.financial_institution_id = loan_data_cur.financial_inst_id
        and    d.prdct_id = loan_data_cur.prdct_id
        and    d.prdct_sub_id = loan_data_cur.prdct_sub_id
        and    d.instrmnt_id = loan_data_cur.instrument_id;

begin
    for loan_data in (
        select distinct *
        from   test
    )
    loop
        for loan_rate in loan_data_cur
            ( loan_data.bndng_typ
            , loan_data.bndng_val
            , loan_data.financial_institution_id
            , loan_data.prdct_id
            , loan_data.prdct_sub_id
            , loan_data.instrmnt_id )
        loop
            update test t set t.seq_num = 1
            where  t.seq_num = 2
            and    t.pos_num = loan_data.pos_num
            and    t.pos_type = loan_data.pos_type
            and    t.price_component_id = loan_rate.price_component_id
            and    t.rprtd_till_dt = loan_data.rprtd_till_dt;

            if sql%rowcount = 0 then
                insert into test values (x, y, z);
            end if;

        end loop;
    end loop;
    
    commit;

end test2;
```

I would also looking at doing the join from `test` to `test1` as a single cursor instead of explicitly with two separate cursors, as the optimiser might find a more efficient method, such as a hash join.

Probably the `update`/`insert` combination could be written as a single `merge`. Once you have a `merge` working, you might find you can apply it to the whole table in one shot and not need any cursor loops at all.

Bulk-collecting into an array could be useful if the number of row-by-row updates causes performance problems (if it's more than a few thousand, say). If so, you would want to structure it so that you could apply the updates/inserts using a `forall` construction, not more loops.